# Make touch dragging work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

I'm developing a web application in Chrome on a Ubuntu touchscreen laptop.

Part of this application requires that the user be able to drag across an element while the application keeps track of the path the mouse makes across the element. This works fine for dragging with the mouse, however when I drag across the element with the touchscreen Chrome just scrolls the whole page.

I tried adding `event.preventDefault()` into my `click()` function, however this does not prevent the touch drag scrolling.

```
var drawing = false;
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', function(event){click(event);});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){if(drawing) click(event);});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){if(drawing) click(event);});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){drawing=true;});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){drawing=true;});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchend', function(event){drawing=false;});
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){drawing=false;});
```

I need to be able to follow the path the user drags across the touchscreen, without it scrolling the whole page.

Comment: you need to show us the code.

Comment: I added the code that assigns the event listeners, however I don't think it will help much. Is there any specific code part that you think would be helpful?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle, if you can.